# How to assign onclick event on multiple elements with same ID

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm trying to make a simple like button who, when a user clicks on this button, the like stay red.

I make a class for my 4 buttons, but it's not really efficient, so, I would like to find an other way to do that.

When the user clicks on a like button :
---- If The user already liked : Unlike (toggle off .active)
---- Else                      : Like (toggle on .active)

How I display the like button :

```
<svg id="articleFooter_like" <!-- Other params -->>
  <!-- Path here -->
</svg>

<svg id="articleFooter_like" <!-- Other params -->>
  <!-- Path here -->
</svg>

<svg id="articleFooter_like" <!-- Other params -->>
  <!-- Path here -->
</svg>
```

My code (works for one button, but not when there is more than one like)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#articleFooter_like').click(function()
  {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
}
```

Button's style :

```
#articleFooter_like
{
  fill: white;
}

#articleFooter_like:hover, #articleFooter_like.active
{
  fill: red;
}
```

To focus multiple ids, I tried (doesn't works) :

```
$('[id=articleFooter_like]').each(function() 
{
    var outerThis = $(this);
    outerThis.click(function() 
    { 
        $(this).toggleClass(".active");
    });
});
```

Comment: You should never have multiple elements with the same ID `articleFooter_like` convert the id Into Class, There is nothing inefficient about that

Comment: What do you find inefficient about using a class?

Comment: no about using a class, but about using like "articleFooter_like_1", "articleFooter_like_2", "articleFooter_like_3"...

Comment: Using classes *is the correct way to do this*, so you can have 1 piece of code that works for all the groups of elements.  Multiple duplicate IDs *is wrong*.  Rather than try to force people to give you bad code to make a bad design work, why not let us advise you how to do this correctly so that a) it works and b) you learn the right way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

Try using classes like this.

```js
    var $likeButtons = jQuery('.articleFooter_like')
    $likeButtons.click(function() {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('action')
    })
```

```css
.action {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="like1" class="articleFooter_like">1</div>
<div id="like2" class="articleFooter_like">2</div>
<div  id="like3" class="articleFooter_like">3</div>
```

if you wanted to select multiple ids you could do something like:

```
jQuery('[id^=like]').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('action')
})
```

Answer (score -2):

## **I don't recomend that and I would use classes instead.**

but in jquery you can use attribute search:

```
$(['id=articleFooter_like]')
```

**Working demo with search by ids:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id=articleFooter_like]').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
})
```

```css
#articleFooter_like
{
  fill: blue;
}

#articleFooter_like:hover, #articleFooter_like.active
{
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="articleFooter_like" >
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>

<svg id="articleFooter_like" >
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>

<svg id="articleFooter_like" >
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

**Real scenario**

What I would do in a real scenario It's changing the `id="articleFooter_like"` for `class="articleFooter_like"` and it would look like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.articleFooter_like').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
})
```

```css
.articleFooter_like
{
  fill: blue;
}

.articleFooter_like:hover, .articleFooter_like.active
{
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="articleFooter_like" >
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>

<svg class="articleFooter_like" >
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>

<svg class="articleFooter_like" >
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: You might find the ["Attribute Starts With" selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) useful. But why not just use a class?

Comment: Daniel you should never have multiple Elements with the same ID, it's in general a big no no

Comment: I totally said it, I won't recommend that, but it's the answer to the question.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen You never know the requirements of other people, maybe the svg can be another company, etc... I would go totally with your answer  in a real scenario.